# Crystal report formula error passing parameter

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am creating a Crystal report to passing parameters to display the record if I wrote the formula error.
there is an error in this formula.

```
{records.id}={?idparam}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Crystal Syntax the equal sign by itself `=` is a comparison operator.  The assignment operator is a colon followed by an equal sign `:=`.

Try changing your formula to `{records.id} := {?idparam}`.

Comment: {records.id} := {?idparam} i tied again formula error

Comment: What are the data types for `{records.id}` and `{?idparam}`?  They need to have the same data types for this formula.